# Delete duplicate entries with lower IDs

Tags: sql, time-limit-exceeded, sql-server, t-sql

I have a function that deletes duplicate entries.  The highest ID is kept and the older ones are removed.

*function*:

```
DELETE [tableName]
FROM [tableName]
INNER JOIN (SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY [fork_id] ORDER BY ID DESC) 
           AS RowNumber FROM [tableName])
Numbered ON [tableName].ID = Numbered.ID
WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

For example, it changes

```
|------|---------|--------|
|  ID  | fork_id |   Car  |
|------|---------|--------|
|  1   |    2    |  AUDI  | <--- removed
|  2   |    1    |  AUDI  |
|  3   |    2    |  BMW   |
|------|---------|--------|
```

to

```
|------|---------|--------|
|  ID  | fork_id |   Car  |
|------|---------|--------|
|  2   |    1    |  AUDI  |
|  3   |    2    |  BMW   |
|------|---------|--------|
```

The problem with that query is the execution time exceed time when with have many rows (more than 50k) in the table.

I have a `primary key` for the `ID` column

I'm In the sql server, I have a limitation about execution time.

> A connection can be cut off by the server for a number of reasons:
>
> 1. Idle connection longer than 5 minutes.
> 2. Long running query.
> 3. Long running open transaction.
> 4. Excessive resource usage.
>
> [sources](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7070c2f9-07d1-4935-82c2-b74a196908ee/sql-azure-connection-time-out-problem?forum=ssdsgetstarted)

Comment: what are your indexes on?

Comment: I don't have any index except the `primary key`. Primary keys are always indexed by default. should I do a Index with the `fork_id`column?

Comment: well, if ID, fork_id is unique (paired) a clustered index *could* help. I'm curious as to how long it takes on 100K records.

Comment: The fork_id is not necessary assending or with a particular order. well, it probably a nonclustered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would probably be better on DBA
You can use a CTE
An index on fork_id should help

```
with cte as 
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [fork_id] ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RowNumber 
  FROM [tableName]
)
delete from cte 
WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

Optimize

```
select * from cte 
WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

If that is fast it is volume thing and you could delete in batches

Comment: sorry for the delay.. I have a bug with the "*" in the delete part.  `Failed to execute query. Error: Incorrect syntax near '*'`

Comment: try without the *

Comment: works now :-) but the time are 103s for `Query succeeded: Affected rows: 487665.` with an index on `fork_id`

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond It takes time to delete rows.

Comment: could I use like `select * into AnotherTable from cte WHERE RowNumber > 1` to move all data into another table instead of delete? it could be more quick?  (not working but..)

Comment: That would not move data it would copy and why would you want to copy the data you want to get rid of?

Comment: *yes copy..* I just looking a solution fast to "remove" old data. Well, if extract the good part is the fastest solution, I'll it. I have only 30 seconds to process that.